# Where can I find old HSK tests?

Tags: hsk

I'd like to practice HSK based on tests from previous years, but have trouble finding them. Is there a place where those were collected for the general public?

Comment: What do you mean by "old HSK tests"? HSK was modified in 2010 (two lower levels were added, the others were redefined) and is now sometimes referred to as the "New HSK". So does "old HSK" refer to pre-2010 tests or simply past "New HSK" tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Internet is [full of them](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=hsk+past+papers), starting from https://www.confuciusinstitute.manchester.ac.uk/study/testing/hsk/hsk-learning-resources/

Answer (score -1):

Buy them on [taobao](https://detail.tmall.com/item.htm?spm=a230r.1.14.13.1ec211cdp90a90&id=530416898726&ns=1&abbucket=11), or jd.com, about 60 Kuai a book, usually 8 exams I believe, with a CD for the listening part.
Just enter HSK and the number of the level you want.